# How to read SPECIFIC UNPREDICTED string from a text file in c#

Tags: c#, text

So I Have a .txt file that its content is like:

A = **RANDOM STRING DETERMINED BY THE USER**

B = **RANDOM STRING DETERMINED BY THE USER**

C = **RANDOM STRING DETERMINED BY THE USER**

And want to get the string after "A = " + "B = " + "C = ".

But also keep in mind that each string is RANDOM, so to get them you'll have to get' the string "**A**, **B**, **C** = " and then the string that is next to it would be the RANDOM UNPREDICTED string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```cs
string path = @"E:\1.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var result = lines.Select(s => s.Substring(4));

// Usage:
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// Output:
// 1234567
// 7854963
// aoeuidh
```

1.txt:

```cs
A = 1234567
B = 7854963
C = aoeuidh
```

---

Description:

- [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1) Method:Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file.
- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
- [`String.Substring(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) Method: Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

Do not forget
`using System.Linq;` and
`using System.IO;`.

Comment: Note that this won't work on all flavors of .Net out of the box. It might be better to use `.Substring(4)` than `[4..]`